# Incorrect padding. Django with Google Chrome

Tags: python-3.x, django, google-chrome

Please, skip this first part and look for update section...
I asked the question yesterday, but removed it, because it seems I gave too few information and explained the question poorly. But it is kind of solved, but solutions relate to different problems. I just implemented ideas towards this particular problem and I would like to share it, so it might help to somebody out there.

So the problem I bumped into is: My site is based on the Django app, when I use Google Chrome it interpret it as (as I understand) 32 bit, meanwhile it is 64 bit (I'm not sure if I'm giving here right description of the problem, but general idea is that) and Google Chrome fails and gives following message:

Incorrect padding

What I have done to fix the problem. The solution based on: https://gist.github.com/perrygeo/ee7c65bb1541ff6ac770

So I went into: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/base64.py
Function name is b64decode, it is on the line 87. It looks like:

```
def b64decode(s, altchars=None, validate=False):
    """Decode the Base64 encoded bytes-like object or ASCII string s.

    Optional altchars must be a bytes-like object or ASCII string of length 2
    which specifies the alternative alphabet used instead of the '+' and '/'
    characters.

    The result is returned as a bytes object.  A binascii.Error is raised if
    s is incorrectly padded.

    If validate is False (the default), characters that are neither in the
    normal base-64 alphabet nor the alternative alphabet are discarded prior
    to the padding check.  If validate is True, these non-alphabet characters
    in the input result in a binascii.Error.
    """
    s = _bytes_from_decode_data(s)
    if altchars is not None:
        altchars = _bytes_from_decode_data(altchars)
        assert len(altchars) == 2, repr(altchars)
        s = s.translate(bytes.maketrans(altchars, b'+/'))
        if validate and not re.fullmatch(b'[A-Za-z0-9+/]*={0,2}', s):
        raise binascii.Error('Non-base64 digit found')
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
```

To fix the problem, I changed this line:
return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
into this:
return binascii.a2b_base64(s + b'================================')#corrected

It is may be too many '=', but they will be gone any way... But these equal signs allow Google Chrome define base64 properly...

This fault only happens with Google Chrome.

**Update**
The above approach somehow doesn't really work... It works for one computer with one key and breaks the other computer with different environment key. So the result by itself is not ok.
So, in a view file I have the following code:

```
def index(request):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        num_visits=request.session.get('num_visits', 0)
        request.session['num_visits']=num_visits+1
        context = {
                'now':now,
                num_visits':num_visits,
        }
        return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

So, as soon as I switch off following parts of the code, designed for the session count of the user, everything becomes normal and I have no problem:
num_visits=request.session.get('num_visits', 0)
request.session['num_visits']=num_visits+1
num_visits':num_visits,

So, I guess these lines are source of the 'incorrect padding' fault... But what have I done wrong with them is to be found... Any help would be nice...